Как посмотреть интернет запросы чужого android приложения?
Есть ли способ посмотреть что именно отправляет андроид приложение в интернет? Типа как в меню разработчика в браузере вкладка сеть. Приложение андроид не мое. PacketCapture не показывает тело запроса что как раз и нужно узнать.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Мониторинг трафика в Android

@Kromster, согласен вопрос похожий, но я пытался через PacketCapture но он не показывает тело запроса, а только список запросов

Стоит добавить это уточнение в вопрос )

Подходов к решению задачи множество, но вся их суть сводится к одному: нужно заставить мобилу обращаться через proxy-сервер в роли которого выступает ваш компьютер или роутер, который переадресовывает запросы на ваш комп. Гуглите — "перехват трафика" + Android + мобильных приложений. Выступая в роли сервера вы можете отловить запрос как есть.

@stylok способ может быть и был бы рабочий если бы приложение не закрывало доступ при включении vpn, скорее всего дело в сертификате его надо ставить на уровень системы что в условиях эмулятора похоже что не возможно(эмулятор-android studio, ну я не нашел способа установить(есть конечно программа magisk но в условиях эмулятора ее невозможно скорее всего установить(ну по крайней мере я не смог)))При попытке декомпилировать через приложение APK_Easy_Tool-master спустя 2.5 часа ничего не произошло и логи стоят на месте.

Просмотр трафика приложенияНашел вот эту статью по ней и смог все таки получить разобранные сообщения сервер-клиент и клиент-сервер, делал по части 2 из-за чего приложение уже и не ругалось на сертификат.
